# Why do we have separate functions that return const and non-const?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/), `std::vector::operator[]` has two overloads:

```
      reference operator[] (size_type n);
const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;
```

Why do we need the `const` version of the function? Or, **why don't we just write one non-const function?**

For example, in the following code:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int b = a[1] + a[3];  // Why does it matter if this is const?
```

Comment: No, they both return lvalues...

Comment: @Brian If you have a class `a` with function `const int& getInt() const`, wouldn't `a.getInt() = 5` be illegal?  On the other hand, if it returned a non-const reference, wouldn't it be legal that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const` overload will be called when the object itself is declared `const`. For example, if we only had non-const overload of `operator[]` on `std::vector`, following code would refuse to compile:

```
const std::vector<int> a{10, 20, 30};
int y = a[0];
```

On the other hand, if we don't have non-const overload, following would fail:

```
std::vector<int> a{10, 20, 30};
a[0] = 15;
```

And last, but not the least, none of those functions return `rvalue`. Both return `lvalue`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something stupid here, but why can't the first snippet just call the non-const overload?

Comment: @dma1324 because C++ is a strongly typed language, and `const` is part of the type. A non-const type will decay to a const one when necessary, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The const version exist to for allow element access (read only) of a constant vector. 
Without it a const vector would be a [WOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_memory_(joke)).

The function returns a const reference, meaning that you cannot assign a new value to it but you can copy it elsewhere (if it is copyable).

Answer (score 0):

Well the reference returning version makes it possible to modify the vector using the bracket notation:

```
a[1] = -1;
```

Since the object on the left side is a reference to the entry in the vector, this actually modifies the vector.

The const_reference returning version makes it possible to access the elements of a const vector.

```
const vector<int> a {1, 3};
int x = a[0];
```

This would not compile without the const_reference overload.